# How to do port mapping in docker when running .net core applications?

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

net core project. I have successfully build the project. Below is my dockerfile.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4040
EXPOSE 5050

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MWS.AspNetCoreApis/MWS.AspNetCoreApis.csproj", "MWS.AspNetCoreApis/"]
RUN dotnet restore "MWS.AspNetCoreApis/MWS.AspNetCoreApis.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/MWS.AspNetCoreApis"
RUN dotnet build "MWS.AspNetCoreApis.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MWS.AspNetCoreApis.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
CMD tail -f /dev/null
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MWS.AspNetCoreApis.dll"]
```

I build my application as `docker build -t locationservices .` Here I build my image.  Then when I run my image using `docker run -d locationservices` it gives some long id. When I try to hit http://localhost:40/swagger/index.html or http://localhost:5050/swagger/index.html my web page doesnt open.
When I run >docker run -it locationservices I get below message.

> Hosting environment: Production Content root path: /app Now listening
>   on: http://[::]:80 Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

But I am not able to hit my application using any of the below urls

```
http://localhost:5050/swagger/index.html
http://localhost:4040/swagger/index.html
http://localhost:80/swagger/index.html
```

can someone help me to figure out the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 21):

I am little late to this question.

But the actual problem is that you are telling docker what ports to expose but they don't match the port that ASP.NET Core is listening on.

You need to add a Environment Variable to the Dockerfile that matches your exposed ports like this.

```
EXPOSE 4040
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://*:4040
```

The last line of the file:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

Then run the container using **-p 4040:4040** that way it maps the port to the "outside" world.

Comment: Thanks! "you are telling docker what ports to expose but they don't match the port that ASP.NET Core is listening on." Was what I was missing. Everything makes sense now.

Comment: why the exposed port does not match? it is 4040 where the apsdotnet core app is running afterall.. Is it because you have to force the app to listen on 4040 (through that env variable)?

Answer (score 4):

You can also add docker container run arguments directly into the .csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <DockerfileRunArguments>-p "4040:443" -p "5050:80"</DockerfileRunArguments>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 4):

I was putting `-p 80:80` after the image name when it has to before!

Wrong and doesn't work:
`docker run image_name -p 80:80`

Correct:
`docker run -p 80:80 image_name`

Comment: After almost 30 minutes of debugging, this is what I was doing wrong. All the args (-p , -v) should come before the image name. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have to publish ports when running the container so that when you hit `localhost:someport` the request will be forwarded to the container. This is done by using [`--publish/-p`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose) option when running the container :

```
docker run -d -p 4040:4040 -p 5050:5050 locationservices
```

and now you can access `localhost:5050/swagger/index.html` and `localhost:4040/swagger/index.html`.

Comment: Thanks. I done this and still not working. May be issue with image?

Comment: have you exposed port `80` also ? Using `-p 80:80` and tried to access `localhost:80/app`?

Comment: yes few times back. after that i deleted image and created new one

Comment: I just logged into container and I can see all the dlls.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and found solution. You can pass urls parameter to your entrypoint to start app on some certain port. Example: ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet","watch", "run", "--server.urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5050"]

And if you want to see any changes on save just use volumes otherwise you will have to restart it after change.

I hope it will helps you ;)

Answer (score 0):

Inside the container, the app binds to localhost on port 80. However, that's *inside* the container. When you attempt to hit `http://localhost`, `localhost` in that context is your machine, not the container instance. You need to access the container via its IP on the LAN, not `localhost`.

Comment: run `docker inspect` on the container. The IP will be in the resulting JSON.

Comment: my ip is http://172.17.0.2/. I tried to run as http://172.17.0.2/swagger/index.html and still it doesnt work